# Trouble with Hadoop Native Libraries

Tags: apache, hadoop, cluster-computing, cloudera

Am using

Apache Hadoop 1.0.4

JDK 1.7

CentOS 5.6

When I install Hadoop Cluster with 2-nodes, it runs fine. I am able to see the status through http://:50070 and http://:50030. However when I build the Hadoop native libraries from source, the cluster continues to work fine, but the monitoring app (Jetty) goes for a toss. The above links dont work.

I compile the native libraries after Hadoop installation (which is basically tar -zxvf). The namenode is already formatted before the compilation, but the cluster is not brought up until native libraries are compiled. Any ideas, how to troubleshoot this? Am using simple ant -Dcompile.native=true compile-native command to build native libraries.